# Openlayers draw poylgon remove double click option

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I am building a UI using Openlayers 4. The request I have received is to not allow the user to double click to complete the current `.Draw` interaction. I have manages this on the `LineString` by using the `maxPoints` option and only allowing the user to draw straight lines (as per my requirements).

I need to do the same thing with the `Polygon` but cannot get it to work. I have tried using the `finishCondition` but this does not help.

Is this something that can be done in Openlayers?

JS Fiddle is throwing massive errors on my machine at the minute, I'll add an example as soon as I can.

**EDIT**

Here is a basic [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/m29tsux0/). You can toggle the return boolean from `finishCondition`, when set to true the single and double click end the polygon drawing. When set to false the drawing cannot end.

I need to find the codtion that will allow me to return `false` if the user double clicks and true otherwise.

Comment: Did you use `singleclick` option for `finishCondition`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It actually stops me being able to finish the polygon. Even when I have snapped to the starting point.

Comment: right. but you set maxPoints for finishing. if it doesn't have enough points, how could you end drawing?

Comment: @ChaseChoi I have added max points for line string but not polygon. The use case I have for the line string is to only allow 2 points ever. The use case I have for Polygon is to work exactly as default but remove the ability to double click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a bit of further investigation I have found a solution, shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/jdpvtsu2/).

I have used the `on` `drawstart` event to calculate and set the coordinate of the first point in the polygon, in the `finishCondition` I find the current pixel it is at, then using that to see if it is within 10px of the clicked point, if it is end the polygon if not then keep drawing.

I am happy if anyone out there can show me a more elegant way to do this, but for now this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Had a look go with this aswell, and you can return whether or not the the finish coordinate of the interaction

```
finishCondition: event => {
    return this.interaction.finishCoordinate_ === this.interaction.sketchCoords_[0][0];
};
```